# How does OCL asSet work?

Tags: ocl

I have a question according to *asSet/ asBag/ asSequence/ asOrderedSet*. May I use it on a collection of collection. For example, I have *(Sequence(Bag(Set(A))))*, may I use these operations and what I will receive as a result, if it is possible. Or I need to use *flatten*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OCL 2.0 documentation  [image]

**1)** This mean that the flatten operation, in your case "Sequence(Bag(Set(t))) " returns  the Sequence of "t" objects  -  Sequence(t).
**2)** If you will use "asSet()" operation, you will get the Set(Bag(Set(t)))